# How to update some old Flutter code to latest release

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Flutter app that was started and abandoned about four years ago. The project has resurfaced and I have been fixing the deprecated items that arose due to the updates made to Flutter in that time period. I have all but one area ready to begin testing, and that is reading from a Firebase Realtime Database into a List. The following is the code that has the error:

```
  return await dbReference
  .orderByChild(AppDatabase._speciesCommonName)
  .startAt(prefix)
  .endAt('$prefix\uf8ff')
  .once()
  .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//
// Make sure we have data
//
if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
  dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value) {
    String dbKey = key;
    String commonName = value[AppDatabase._speciesCommonName];
    Species obj = Species(dbKey: dbKey, commonName: commonName);
    list.add(obj);
  });
```

The error I get is:

> The argument type 'List Function(DataSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<List> Function(DatabaseEvent)'.

I have searched and studied this code and the error, however, having been away from Flutter for those years I am failing to figure out the resolution.

A second error is also reported in the above code, however, I am hoping if the inital error is fixed so will this one:

> The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you ever consider re-write entire your program? 4 years is too far old :) Many things changed, plugin & firebase platform now aren't same as before. I think you re-code it will take less time than upgrade...

Comment: Small suggestion.  Stop using .forEach.  It's in there to make JS people feel at home, but it's a pretty poor tool.  Use explicit for loops, or collection-for.

Answer (score 1):

in terminal

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-verions
```

then attempt to adapt the current code to the new update; occasionally, you will need to change the entirety of a package because some of them are discounted.

Comment: This is where I started until I met the errors I described which I did not understand.

Comment: make sure you clean the project and delete the biuld folder and pubspec.lock file

Answer (score 0):

Provide more code please. 
What's the result being assigned to? When is it called?

---

As for the `forEach` error, you have assumed that `dataSnapshot.value` will be a `List` but it's not hence it isn’t working.